# get Whatsapp Status Images and Videos in Android 11 by Using StorageManager

Tags: java, android, whatsapp, android-11, saf

by using [this Stack OverFlow Answer (FOR SDK 30 AND ABOVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68408220) I well able to retrieve the number of media files present in the .Status Folder on Android 11

But When I set the path to Imageview, image view Show Blanks

```
WAStatusModel fileItem = fileArrayList.get(i);
 File backupFile = new File( fileItem.getPath() );
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(backupFile);    
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUri)
                .into(viewHolder.imgpc);
```

I Also Try with the provider But no effect i.e

```
 Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", backupFile);
Glide.with(context)
                    .load(photoURI)
                    .into(viewHolder.imgpc);
```

My Output paths are::
imageUri is

```
 file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/img.jpg
```

fileItem.getUri() is

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses%2Fimg.jpg
```

and fileItem.getPath() is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/img.jpg
```

image is not Loaded in Adapter. How it is possible.
Plz Help Me

Comment: You should use the uri for the file itself to access the file. You tried to get 'a real path' for an uri. Which is a bad idea but you managed to get a path indeed. But you can do nothing with that path as you have discovered as you have no read permission for it.

Comment: @blackapps are You Mean i use fileItem.getUri()

Comment: If that gives you the uri of the file then yes. You put the uries in the list. Now use them one by one.

Comment: Thanks, Probleme is Solve i get All the Files